L^2 estimate Maxwell equation
I consider the Poisson formulation of Maxwell equation, weakly in $L^2$,
\begin{equation} -\Delta\Psi = B \end{equation}
I understand that under the Coulomb gauge $\mathrm{div}\, A = 0$ where $A$ solves weakly
\begin{equation} \mathrm{rot}\, A = B, \end{equation}
we can deduce that
\begin{equation} A = \mathrm{rot} \,\psi = -\mathrm{rot}\, \Delta^{-1} B. \end{equation}
However I do not understand how to find the following  $L^2$ estimate for $|\mathrm{grad}\,A|_{L^2} \le C|B|_{L^2}$. This is sensible because on the left-hand side there is one gradient which corresponds essentially to one derivative, same as in the right-hand size since $-\Delta^{-1}$ smooth out. However, I do not see how to make this explicit. Any help would be appreacitated.

For future readers, one can just Fourier everything and use standard identities...
